# Cannot cat files with 640 permission while being part of their group

Tags: permissions, users, groups

I've spend hours trying to find why it's not going right, but I give up now so here I am.

My setup/problem: I have a remote VPS to which I connect via SSH (pub/priv keys, no password).
The user is debian.
On this VPS, I run a `postgres:14.3-alpine` docker container.

This docker has two volumes mounted in /home/debian:
postgres-certs
postgres-data

The user/group id of the user in the docker is 70. More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55072885):
As you may know there are security rules around certificates so, as explained in the link above, I have set rights 640 to `postgres-certs` folder:

```
drw-r-----  2    0   70 4096 jun  7 22:45 postgres-certs
drwxr----- 19   70 1000 4096 jun 11 20:40 postgres-data
```

As you can see both folders have group read rights.
please find my groups:

```
debian@db-dev:~$ id
uid=1000(debian) gid=1000(debian) groups=1000(debian),70(docker-pg-alpine),998(docker)
```

As you can see, I'm in groups 70 and 1000, the same defined in the two folders
If I try to cat a file in one of these folders, here's what I get (it works of course if I sudo it):

```
debian@db-dev:~$ cat postgres-certs/server.crt 
cat: postgres-certs/server.crt: Permission denied
```

Just to prove you the file has the same permissions as his directory:

```
debian@db-dev:~$ sudo ls -ln postgres-certs/server.crt 
-rw-r----- 1 0 70 2903 jun  7 22:44 postgres-certs/server.crt
```

Yes, I have logged out (disconnected ssh, even rebooted), I also stopped my container to make sure it does not cause any trouble.
**I just don't understand why I can't cat a damn file in these folders while they have group read rights and I'm in the groups...**
If you guys can find what's wrong, that would be wonderful.

Comment: Explore your Mount/Read/Write/Execute problems with `https://github.com/waltinator/pathlld`, a `bash` script to show the permissions, mount options along the path to an object or objects.

Comment: What are the permissions of the directory?

Comment: @walinator pathlld gives the following:

debian@db-dev:~$ ./pathlld.sh postgres-certs/server.crt 
drw-r----- 2 root docker-pg-alpine 4096 jun  7 22:45 postgres-certs
/bin/ls: cannot access 'postgres-certs/server.crt': Permission denied

Comment: @mchid, the permissions of the folder are the following: <br/>drw-r-----  2    0   70 4096 jun  7 22:45 postgres-certs

Comment: Yes, sorry I missed that. Answer is below. Also, to format code in replies, you can use a single backtik before and after code instead of <br/> (one before and one after).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**To access the files, you need to have `x` set for the directory.**

- For a file, (x) allows you to execute if the file is a program.
- For a directory, (x) allows you to enter a directory and access the files.

---

According to [the `chmod` manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/man1/chmod.1.html), (x) allows search permission for directories.

> The  letters  rwxXst  select  file  mode bits for the affected users: read (r), write (w),
> execute (or search for directories) (x), execute/search only if the file is a directory or
> already  has  execute permission for some user (X), set user or group ID on execution (s),
> restricted deletion flag or sticky bit (t).

According to this [Unix File System document](http://web.mit.edu/sipb/doc/working/afs/html/subsection3.1.html), (x) allows you to enter the directory and access the files.

> For directories, execute permission allows you to enter the directory (i.e., cd into it), and to access any of its files.

---

**For future reference**, you could use:

```
sudo chmod g+x ~/postgres-certs
```

to add (x) permission for the group on a directory.

**However, instead of changing the permission to 650, you should probably use:**

```
sudo cat postgres-certs/server.crt
```

instead so you can maintain the default permission set for the directory.

Comment: Thanks mchid and @waltinator for your quick answer.

for the sudo cat, of course that would work, but I needed my normal debian user to be able to read the files, (in order to read and copy them from scp) while not have too wide permissions for pg docker to start.
Thanks to you I was now able to finish my script connecting the the dev db server, scp everything on local machine and running a local copy of the db in docker.

Comment: @pintaf Neat. If this fixes your problem, don't forget to mark this as the solution by clicking the checkmark icon to the left.